# mysql pconnect , when it close connection

Tags: php, mysql

In genral ,

for mysql_connect have mysql_close ,

but mysql_pconnect does not have any close function ,

i saw in all threads and tutorial , they are saying that for mysql pconnect ,

```
First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent)
link that's already open with the same host, username and password.
If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of 
opening a new connection. 

FRO ---> php.net manual
```

b default there is no close function for mysql_pconnect , then in tutorial,

why they are saying like

> the function would first try to find a
>   (persistent)
>       link that's already open with the same host

As per this line :-- may be in some occasion,  mysql_pconnect connection will close ,

Then when this connection will close ,in which situation connection goes close mode ,

or is there any  time out for cloase connection or time limit ,

i guess this quesiton little but childish ,

Comment: You rarely need to close a MySQL connection in PHP. And use persistent connections only if it's appropriate for your case. Get a grasp on how persistent connections work and when they should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The connection will be closed when the web server or FastCGI process dies.

Comment: web server dies means shall i take it as web server down

Comment: Or when a child has reached `MaxRequests`.